# Hook_boot and user access

Tags: drupal, hook, drupal-modules

I'm overriding hook_boot in my drupal 7.10 project, and trying to load a user account from it. I get the following error.

> Call to undefined function entity_load()

Any ideas why that might be happening? Here is my code.

```
function appcore_boot() {
   drupal_load('module', 'user');
   $account = user_load(array('uid' => 1)); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't move it into `hook_init` then an easy way to ensure `common.inc` is loaded is by calling:

```
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Just place this inside your `hook_boot` before you call `user_load`.  You might not even need `DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL` to get `common.inc` loaded, but that is what I tested it against.

What pointed me here is the documentation for [current_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7) which says:

> This function is not available in hook_boot() so use $_GET['q'] instead. However, be careful when doing that because in the case of Example #3 $_GET['q'] will contain "path/alias". If "node/306" is needed, calling drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL) makes this function available.

Comment: great answer. I ran into this issue too. Thank for your answer. BTW, is there some site effect that comes with "drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);"?

Comment: Running drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL) triggers hook_init before your code runs in hook_boot. Thus there is no meaning in using hook_boot if you are going to trigger full bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

user_load() calls user_load_multiple(), which calls entity_load(), which is stored in common.inc. However, "This hook is called before modules or most include files are loaded into memory. It happens while Drupal is still in bootstrap mode.

Is there any reason why you don't use hook_init():

```
function appcore_init() {
  $account = user_load(array('uid' => 1)); 
}
```

Comment: I can't use hook_init because I need this to be called regardless of weather the page is cached or not. I've seen a few examples of people using user_load in this hook and nobody else seems to be running into this issue which is why I thought it was strange. Is there any way around that? Is it safe to simply load the common.inc file at this point?

Comment: Makes sense Morgan and I can't think of any reason why you can't load common.inc. Let me know if it works and I'll edit my post above.